# What do I need to do to split a washing machine hookup to allow adding a dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, dishwasher

In my new (1836— just moved in) house I have a washing machine in a, um, short hallway? cupboard? leading from a kitchen to a bathroom. Above it is a shelf. The plan is to move the washing machine up onto this shelf and put a dishwasher below.

Here's what it looks like now:
[image: washing machine under shelf]

The washing machine is presumably a cold-water hookup + waste. I've read that dishwashers take a hot-water hookup. Are we already into call-a-plumber territory?

The shelf I want to move the washing machine up onto looks to be well-supported, but how can I tell whether it will hold a full, spinning washing machine?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, a general contractor would do it, sub-contracting all the plumbing work to a licensed plumber.  If you can do all the work that doesn't involve plumbing, you can call around and get estimates, and choose a plumber you like.

From the photo, it looks like you will need to make the support stronger, keeping in mind that the washer is full of water and its center of mass shifts rapidly during operation.  You will also need to robustly attach the washer to the support so it doesn't vibrate off and fall to the floor.

Comment: Bad idea. Washers vibrate too much to put on a shelf. They need to be on the floor. Also, you'll have a time just getting your clothes in and out of the machine. Don't do it. Find another place for your dishwasher.

Comment: @getterdun I agree that they vibrate a lot and you would need to put in measures to make sure that it doesn't fall down.  But to say that you shouldn't do it because of this concern is silly. You can surely raise it in a way that it wouldn't fall.  It would seem to be easier to get the clothes in and out.  You wouldn't have to stoop.  I don't think it's a bad idea for a small place.

Comment: Well @Edwin I have to agree with you re loading and unloading the clothes. I didn't notice that it's a front loader. Too hasty on my opinion. But, apart from the vibration, accessing the water connections and servicing the machine will still be daunting. Hopefully he has room to put it somewhere else.